# Using Random Forest for time series dataset

Tags: time-series, modeling, random-forest

For a time series dataset, I would like to do some analysis and create prediction model. Usually, we would split data (by random sampling throughout entire data set) into training set and testing set and use the training set with randomForest function. and keep the testing part to check the behaviour of the model.

However, I have been told that it is not possible to split data by random sampling for time series data.

I would appreciate if someone explain how to split data into training and testing for time series data. Or if there is any alternative to do time series random forest.
Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We live in a world where "future-to-past-causality" only occurs in cool scifi movies. Thus, when modeling time series we like to avoid explaining past events with future events. Also, we like to verify that our models, strictly trained on past events, can explain future events.

To model time series T with RF rolling is used. For day t, value T[t] is the target and values T[t-k] where k= {1,2,...,h}, where h is the past horizon will be used to form features. For nonstationary time series, T is converted to e.g. the relatively change Trel. = (T[t+1]-T[t]) / T[t].

To evaluate performance, I advise to check the out-of-bag cross validation measure of RF. Be aware, that there are some pitfalls possibly rendering this measure over optimistic:

1. Unknown future to past contamination - somehow rolling is faulty and the model using future events to explain the same future within training set.
2. Non-independent sampling: if the time interval you want to forecast ahead is shorter than the time interval the relative change is computed over, your samples are not independent.
3. possible other mistakes I don't know of yet

In the end, everyone can make above mistakes in some latent way. To check that is not happening you need to validate your model with back testing. Where each day is forecasted by a model strictly trained on past events only.

When OOB-CV and back testing wildly disagree, this may be a hint to some bug in the code.

To backtest, do rolling on T[t-1 to t-traindays]. Model this training data and forecast T[t]. Then increase t by one, t++, and repeat.

To speed up you may train your model only once or at every n'th increment of t.

Answer (score 0):

Reading Sales File

```
Sales<-read.csv("Sales.csv")
```

Finding length of training set.

```
train_len=round(nrow(Sales)*0.8) 
test_len=nrow(Sales)
```

Splitting your data into training and testing set here I have considered 80-20 split you can change that. Make sure your data in sorted in ascending order.

Training Set

```
training<-slice(SubSales,1:train_len)
```

Testing Set

```
testing<-slice(SubSales,train_len+1:test_len)
```